# Swift/Parse - How to preload data when app first opens so I don't ha?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, image-preloader

I have a fairly strong understanding of the Parse basics - saving and querying, etc. However, I need to know how to save objects ( preload ) when the apps initial startup. By initial startup I mean every time the app freshly opened, as opposed to running in the background.

For example, I want to preload five images to be used later. I want to load them in the beginning so it doesn't lag later.

Answer (score 0):

You can start downloading it when your app first open, in AppDelegate's method

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

but if this is a request for a a server and the images are not downloaded yet, you'll need to start a task to download it and just after it completes, you may load your application.
In case of images you could use a placeholder image while you download the right ones.